# Unreadable Windows DVD

Tags: windows, dvd

I have disks burnt commercially on a windows system, which my 2010 iMac (OS X 10.8.2) refuses to read.

I know the disks are correctly burnt for windows (tried them on the vendor's win machine - probably xp) but os x says:

> "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer"

I've no idea what to try (short of accessing them on an at work win machine.
Any pointers out there?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities. There is a problem with the software and/or hardware on your Mac, *or* the disk wasn't truly burned properly.

If your Mac reads all other DVDs fine, I'm guessing the problem is with how it was burned.

I'm not sure what software or method you used, but maybe there's a problem with the partition or something on the DVDs. Try to see what it says in Disk Utility.

Answer (score 0):

As A L pointed out, there are two possible things that are broken. The DVD, or your Mac. Try downloading an official ISO from Microsoft Digital River and burning that to a blank DVD, using your Mac (Use Disk Utility, there are many good tutorials out there if you don't know how) and try that. If it doesn't work, the problem is with your Mac's hardware.

I don't know how to troubleshoot optical drives; so you could ask about that here, Google it, or take your computer to the Genius Bar. Most of the time, if you are nice, they will tell you what's wrong with it for free.